# section não funciona corretamente

Tags: html, css, html5

Preciso que minha `<section>` fique igual a desse site [aqui](https://www.destinythegame.com/pt) segue a imagem da parte que eu preciso[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei codificar porem não fica de forma alguma desse jeito não sei onde estou errando.

Segue meu código:

**CSS**

```
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.imagem {
  background-image: url(http://nerdreactor.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/destiny_thumbnail-500x300_c.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 59.42%;
}
.info li {
  width: 33.3333%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.text {
  background-color: lime;
  height: 320px;
}
.text p {
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 95%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="info-geral">
  <ul class="info">
    <li>
      <div class="imagem">
        <div class="text">
          <h3>DEI UMA ATUALIZADA CONFORME FUI MECBHENDO AQUI</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </li>


  </ul>
</section>
```

OBS: Estava mexendo aqui e dei uma atualizada deu uma melhorada mais ainda acho que não esta correto

Comment: tente fazer um padding no h3 e no paragrafo.

Comment: como assim um padding de que  top bottom ?

Comment: use: .text h3, p { padding: 5px 10px; } esse trecho vai criar um espaço entre as bordas e deixar os textos mais centralizados dentro da div text

Comment: Seu CSS está certo. O problema é que só tem um li. Pra ficar igual no site você precisa de três <li>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, só faltou você adicionar mais elementos `li` dentro da tag `ul`.

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.imagem {
  background-image: url(http://nerdreactor.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/destiny_thumbnail-500x300_c.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 59.42%;
}
.info li {
  width: 33.3333%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.text {
  background-color: lime;
  height: 320px;
}
.text p {
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 95%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<section id="info-geral">
  <ul class="info">
    <li>
      <div class="imagem">
        <div class="text">
          <h3>DEI UMA ATUALIZADA CONFORME FUI MECBHENDO AQUI</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </li>
<li>
      <div class="imagem">
        <div class="text">
          <h3>DEI UMA ATUALIZADA CONFORME FUI MECBHENDO AQUI</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </li>
      <li>
      <div class="imagem">
        <div class="text">
          <h3>DEI UMA ATUALIZADA CONFORME FUI MECBHENDO AQUI</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```